# How many Shapes are possible to create using Voxels?

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry, permutations

Let's suppose I have Big Cube of x cm by y cm by z cm, simmilar to this one:
[image]

This big cube is made of tiny little cubes of t cm.

All of this little cubes are transparent, but some of them are red

How many arrangements of little red cubes is it possible to do?

I think this is a permutations with repetition problem, and so far, this is the equation I came with:

$$ a= ( \sum_{n=0}^{A} P_{A}^{A-n,n} )^Z   $$

Where:

$ a= $ Number of possible arrangements

$ Z= $ Value of the number of layers equal to $z/t$

$ A= $ Area of each layer equal to $(x/t)(y/t)$

$ P_n^{n_1,...,n_r}=$ Notation for Permutations with Repetition

So, for example, if it is used the values of the example, it is obtained this:

$$ a = ( \sum_{n=1}^{64} P_{64}^{64-n,n} )^8 = (18,446,744,073,709,551,616)^8 $$

But my problem is: How many arragenments of little cubes can I do, so that the all the red cubes touch each other, so that there is no isolated geometries?

For example, this one is valid, it is only one geometry:

[image]

This one is not valid, there are two shapes separated:

[image]

I suppose that the orginal formula, must have a term that gets rid of the cases with Isolated Shapes

$$  ( \sum_{n=0}^{A} P_{A}^{A-n,n} ) ^Z - (IsolatedShapes)  $$

What's the value of that "IsolatedShapes" Term?, Could you give some ideas of how to tackle this problem?

Comment: Exact enumeration of connected shapes is a challenge. You might liken it to graph enumeration of graphs of bounded degree, with additional properties like being bipartite and connected (let vertices be cube centers, with an edge between adjacent cubes).  There should be tables of earlier attempts on the web.  Gerhard "Is Confronting Other Challenges Presently" Paseman, 2020.05.09.

Comment: But at least, Do you know if my formula for the General Case is correct?

Comment: I am unsure about your formula, as I do not understand it.  One has an upper bound of 2^(Z^3) by considering subsets of cubes, but this assumes no symmetry collapse (e.g. there are Z^3 many figures, each with exactly one cube, in a different positions) and counts disconnected arrangements.  You might find counting connected arrangements in a layer just as challenging, but then you could use that for tighter approximations.  Gerhard "Go Ahead: Try A Slice" Paseman, 2020.05.09.

Comment: This reminds me a lot of [the enumeration of LEGO structures](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/10586458.2011.564539), a famously difficult problem.